# how to get a node name from an unknown node via SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, nodename

For example I have 2 types of nodes in my xml file:

```
    1) <book>
    2) <author>
```

A variable named $node points to specific node(of unknown type).
How can I access this node's name? It must be something like this:

```
    if($node->name()=="book")
    process_book($node);
    else
    process_author;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement` has a [`getName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php) method:

```
echo $node->getName();
```

**Assumption:** `$node` is a SimpleXMLElement object.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but here is a simlpe solution. Change `simplexml_load_string` to `simplexml_load_file` if your using a file.

```
$xml_string = <<<XML
<root>
    <item>
        <book>Book 1</book>
        <author>Author 1</author>
    </item>
    <item>
        <book>Book 2</book>
        <author>Author 2</author>
    </item>
    <item>
        <book>Book 3</book>
        <author>Author 3</author>
    </item>
</root>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

foreach($xml->item as $node){
    if(isset($node->book)){
        process_book($node);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, $node points to the PARENT of the node that you process. That's not what I need, but thanks.